# Marking/Tagging Image using jquery taggd

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using This Plugin [taggd](http://www.timseverien.nl/taggd/#items) to create an app which on click on any part of body creates a  tag so far i have managed everything just this coordinates not getting right its creating dots on document sometimes and sometimes near my click on picture if i click on left top corner . So the problem is its not creating the point where i click on the picture  unable to understand thats whats wrong with my coordinate not much help on documentation .

It takes scale 0-1 or in pixels but that's also not understood

**Question**
How to make it work properly to take exact coordinates and put tag exactly where i click.

[image: a Model]

```
<html>

   <head>
      <link href='css/taggd.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.taggd.js"></script>


   </head><body>




      <img  id="mytag" class="taggd" src="img/front.jpg"/>


         <script type="text/javascript">
var data = [];
var settings = [];

$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.taggd').click(function(e) {
     var offset = $(this).offset();
  var x = (e.pageX - offset.left);
  var y = (e.pageY - offset.top);


   console.log(x);
   console.log(y);

   data.push([
{ x:x/100, y:y/100, text: 'Huey This is a text' }


]);

settings.push({
align: { 'y': 'top' },
offset: { 'top': 100 },

'handlers': {
'mouseenter': 'show',
'mouseleave': 'hide'
}
});


$('.taggd').each(function(i, e) {
var $e = $(e);
 console.log(e);
$e.taggd(settings[i]);
$e.taggd('items', data[i])
});
});


});




/*

         $(document).ready(function() {
 var settings = {
        'align': {
            'x': 'center',
            'y': 'center'
        },

        'handlers': {},

        'offset': {
            'left': 0,
            'top': 0
        }
    };








            $('#mytag').click(function(e) {
       $('#mytag').taggd(settings);
               var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
               var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
               console.log(x);
               console.log(y);









               $('#mytag').taggd('items',  {x: x, y: y, text: 'This is a test'})




            });
         });



*/
      </script>




   </body></html>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Question is its not taking coordinates right . How to take exact cordinates when click on image so it creates tag there

Comment: Well that depends on your page structure also whether you've scroll or not etc..

Comment: This might finally actually be a valid use case for `<input type="image">` returning coordinates!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to reply for completeness anyway.

## How to generate static coordinates

Many users got stuck at generating coordinates. It’s annoying to open an image in Photoshop and look up the coordinates of all tags. Because of that, I created a generator:

https://timseverien.com/projects/taggd/generator/

## How to create coordinates real-time

Like the generator, it is possible to generate (and modify) data real-time.

```
var $img = $('my-image');
var taggd = $img.taggd(options, data);

$img.on('mousedown', function(e) {
  // Get parent offset to calculate relative position
  var poffset = $(this).parent().offset();
  var x = e.pageX - poffset.left;
  var y = e.pageY - poffset.top;

  // By dividing the x and y coordinates with the
  // image’s width and height, you get a number
  // between 0 and 1, which is safer for scaling

  taggd.addData({
    x: x / $img.width(),
    y: y / $img.height(),
    text: Math.random()
  });
});
```

Comment: hello @Tim, thanks for your post, i need something similiar with your code, but i need to add some input fields, for example a title to let the user choose wich title to insert in the tag, how i would do that?

Comment: @Pedro In 2.x you can use the (undocumented) edit option `{edit: true}` to enable in-page editing. As of 3.x, you can use [`taggd.enableEditorMode()`](https://doclets.io/timseverien/taggd/master#dl-Taggd-enableEditorMode) instead.